# Suspicious behavior of Windows Form after using unsafe code with ZeroMQ

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pointers, zeromq

I am using ZeroMQ inside Windows Form application in C#. The ZeroMQ is using Publisher-Subscriber pattern and consists of 3 publishers to publish 3 different types of data. Below is the code snippet-

```
var ZmqContext = new ZContext();
ZmqContext.SetOption(ZContextOption.IO_THREADS, 3);

var DataType1Publisher = new ZSocket(zmqContext, ZSocketType.PUB);
var DataType2Publisher = new ZSocket(zmqContext, ZSocketType.PUB);
var DataType3Publisher = new ZSocket(zmqContext, ZSocketType.PUB);

DataType1Publisher.SetOption(ZSocketOption.CONFLATE, 1);
DataType1Publisher.Bind("tcp://*:10001");
DataType2Publisher.SetOption(ZSocketOption.CONFLATE, 1);
DataType2Publisher.Bind("tcp://*:10002");
DataType3Publisher.SetOption(ZSocketOption.CONFLATE, 1);
DataType3Publisher.Bind("tcp://*:10003");

DataType1Publisher.Send(new ZFrame(DataType1ByteArray));
DataType2Publisher.Send(new ZFrame(DataType2ByteArray));
DataType3Publisher.Send(new ZFrame(DataType3ByteArray));
```

The `DataType1ByteArray`, `DataType2ByteArray` and `DataType3ByteArray` are `byte` array manually composed by converting `uint` and `float` data into `byte` array as follows-

```
int MAX_LENGTH = 100;
byte[] DataType1ByteArray = new byte[MAX_LENGTH];
int DataType1ByteArrayIndex = 0;

unsafe private void AddUint(uint point)
{
    byte* bytePtr = (byte*)&point;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(uint); i++)
    {
        DataType1ByteArray[DataType1ByteArrayIndex++] = bytePtr[i];
    }
}

unsafe private void AddFloat(float point)
{
    byte* bytePtr = (byte*)&point;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(float); i++)
    {
        DataType1ByteArray[DataType1ByteArrayIndex++] = bytePtr[i];
    }
}
```

Below are my observations-

1. The code works smoothly for few hours and successfully transmits data at 700 MBPS rate approximately.
2. It stops transmitting any data after 5-6 hours.
3. There is no error reported in Visual Studio.
4. When I see the "Task Manager" in PC (Windows 10), the ethernet shows 0Kbps.

Please note that **the code works fine with [BitConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) class**. However, for faster speed, I used `byte* bytePtr = (byte*)&point` since it is much faster than `BitConverter`.

Though I am not sure it seems some kind of memory leakage. How to debug this issue and make it working? Any workaround, please?

Comment: "so, I used unsafe in C# and then several hours later, code stops working" - sounds  like a memory leak.  Did you really need that extra speed? Perhaps you really have an XY problem?

Comment: @MitchWheat: Yes. This time, speed is really needed. I also think that it is memory leak but how to confirm it? I am using Visual Studio Community Edition on Windows 10 64 Bit OS. Thank you very much.